# Apply transformation over dataframe instead of element-wise (for audio files)

Tags: python, pandas, audio

I am dealing with a data frame with over 8000 rows. Each tuple consists of a path to an audio file for which a spectrogram needs to be created. One solution would be to use `itertuples`, iterating row-wise and converting each audio sample one at a time.

```
for row in valid_data.itertuples():
    y, sr = librosa.load('code/UrbanSound8K/audio/' + row.path, duration=2.97)  
    ps = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr)
    D.append( (ps, row.classID) )
```

But I'm not a fan of iterating over a dataframe. Is there a more efficient way to do this by applying an operation over all rows at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is going to help you, but my idea is to use threads (available in many OO languages) I don't know if you computer is going to be able to handle all the rows, but you can work for example with 4 rows at the same time, of course you will have to modify the "for" counter.